# Find next element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do have some html like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="sequence valid">
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="sequence valid">
</div>  

<div class="someclass1">
    <div class="someclass2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="sequence valid">
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="sequence valid">
        </div> 
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="sequence valid">
</div> 

<div class="someclass1">
    <div class="someclass2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="sequence valid">
        </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this what I need is, to find next element which contain `.sequence` withing a `form-group`.

This is how I tried it in jquery:

```
var $element = $(event.target);
  if ($element.hasClass('valid')) {
        $element.closest('.form-group')
            .next('.form-group')
            .find('.sequence')

    }
```

But its not select the elements within this block of code:

```
<div class="someclass1">
    <div class="someclass2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="sequence valid">
        </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody tell me how can I modify this jquery to match my requirement. 
Thank you.

Comment: how are you firing the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `.next('.form-group')` is finding the target element as the `someclass1` element is not matching the selector

```
$element.closest('.form-group')
    .next('.form-group, :has(.form-group)')
    .find('.sequence')
```

or you can omit the selector in `next` and find the `.sequence` element in the next sibling element

```
$element.closest('.form-group')
    .next()
    .find('.sequence')
```